# Excel hanging while refreshing SAP Business Explorer query

Tags: microsoft-excel, sap

I have two PCs running Excel 2003 and SAP Business Explorer 7.2. I'm trying to refresh the queries within a spreadsheet that has 30 tabs and at least one query on each tab.

When I refresh all the queries on my own PC, they all update successfully. It takes less than ten minutes to refresh the whole spreadsheet.

When I try it on this client's PC, Excel refreshes the first tab just as I'd expect but then hangs. I've left it for over an hour and it hasn't made any progress. While it's hung the CPU usage for the Excel.exe process hits and stays constant at 50% (it's a dual core PC, I'm guessing it would hit higher perhaps 100% if it was a single core), but strangely even though it is sitting constantly at 50% CPU no activity appears within Process Monitor once it has hung. I've also run Microsoft's Network Monitor and I can see network traffic back and forth between Excel and the SAP server right up to the point where Excel hangs, but then nothing after that. I've also tried running the queries under the client's account and my own AD account (which had never been used before on that PC, so was a fresh profile), but no difference. I've also checked Excel.exe with Process Explorer to see if there are any third-party DLLs present but found nothing out of the ordinary, nothing that isn't present on my own PC.

What am I missing? Are there any other tools available that can show me what Excel is doing while it is not responding but using 50% CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out in the end. The spreadsheet was composed of multiple tabs and the other tabs had literally thousands of VLOOKUPs that depended on the data in the first tab. So as soon as Business Explorer refreshed the data in the first tab, Excel was trying to refresh the VLOOKUPs on the other tabs.

Hence Excel maxing out a CPU core and seeming to sit and do nothing for hours.

Answer (score 0):

this is a guess, but is there a difference with the number of simultaneous connections allowed by SAP (or business explorer itself)? this could be a licencing restriction.

Comment: Thanks but no. It's not a licensing issue. Should have mentioned in my original post but if I go into SM50 on the server I can see the initial activity relating to the query on the first tab but then nothing.